# ActiveRecord joins where id array of self

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'd like to chain a query with a joins and a where on the first model

```
FbGroup.joins(:fb_posts).where(id: [1,2])
# this returns a lot of extra rows

FbGroup.joins(:fb_posts).where('fb_groups.id IN (?)', acct_ids)
# also tried this with no luck
```

How can I first filter by fb_groups with specific ids while doing a joins?

Comment: The second seems right, What is the type of your database?

Comment: @Evan postgresql

Answer (score 0):

Does it not work to just use both?

```
FbGroups.joins(:fb_groups).where(id: [1,2]).where('fb_groups.id IN (?)', acct_ids)
```

PS you can also use

```
FbGroups.joins(:fb_groups).where(id: [1,2]).where(fb_groups: {id: acct_ids})
```

or, since both `where`s are now using Hash args:

```
FbGroups.joins(:fb_groups).where(id: [1,2], fb_groups: {id: acct_ids})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FbGroup.distinct.joins(:fb_posts).where
              .not(id: FbGroup.joins(:fb_posts)
                       .where(fb_groups: {id: [1,2]}).distinct)
```